# are there measure preserving mapping in this case?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose f and g are two Borel function on [0, 1].  The push-forward of the Lebesgue measure on [0,1] by f and by g are the same. Then are there some Borel measurable function from [0,1] to [0,1],  such that

f = g(h)?

Comment: I know If f and g are simple functions, the answer is yes.

Comment: Do you mean $f = g\circ h$ almost everywhere? I can give a simple counterexample if you demand $f(t) = g(h(t))$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming push-forward means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) ...

Hint... Consider the two maps $f(x) = \{2x\}$ and $g(x) = \{3x\}$, where the brackets are the fractional part.  What would $h$ be then?

[image: 2x]

[image: 3x]

Comment: I thought of this too, but then I tried to show no $h$ could exist and discovered that it's easy to find an $h$ that works.

Comment: Perhaps we have to distinguish between the problem in the title (measure preserving) and the problem in the text that does not say $h$ is measure preserving.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. Yes, you certainly have a counterexample for $h$ measure preserving. The problem in the text seems more subtle --- here I feel the existence of $h$ should follow from some measurable selection theorem which could only fail for really pathological $g$, if it fails at all.

Comment: For the case where $h$ need not be measure preserving, the hypothesis that $f, g$ have the same distribution is irrelevant: it is enough that $f$ and $g$ have the same range.  But, as Nik notes, the selection $h$ may fail to be Borel measurable: but it may be chosen universally measurable.